# Sails JS: How to pass value from policy to controller

Tags: sails.js

I have a policy which checks whether a request has complete and valid body. I want to send a value to the controller to determine whether the result is passed or failed. Is there anyway to achieve that?

Comment: The [sails gitter room](https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails) is also a good place to chat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why pass control to the controller at all if the policy fails?  Usually the point of a policy like the one you described is to divert program flow if the policy fails, perhaps to an error page.  In any case, what you're looking for is best done using [`req.options`](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/req/req.options):

> req.options allows altering of (or providing defaults for) request parameters without modifying the original object.

You can set a value in `req.options` in your policy, then read it back in your controller without having to modify the actual request.

Comment: Yes I followed your advice. I realized that I'm duplicating the purpose of policies. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Policy gets the request object as input and you can modify that object before sending it to the controller, ie piggyback your data over the request object.

You can do something like this in the policy :

```
req.body.paramname = 'newval';
```

And in the controller, you can get the value

```
var paramFromPoliy =  req.body.paramname;
```

Comment: This will work, but is really not a good idea unless you actually want to modify the request.  `req.body` should ideally represent what was actually sent in the request; if you modify it, you can't tell which values were from the request and which were added later.